# Chrome table extends when wraps

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a table that I set a fixed "name" column width of 200px.

When the text in any row wraps around to the next line (making a 2 line cell,) every other column is extended.  For a reproducible code snippet, see below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table
{
border-collapse:collapse;
}
table, td, th
{
border:1px solid black;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ddddff;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>



<table style="position:fixed;background-color:white;top:0;left:100px;">
        <tr> 
            <td width="200px;">
                Park Name
            </td>
            <td>
                Park Viewed
            </td>
            <td>
                Book Now Button
            </td>
            <td>
                Website Button
            </td>
            <td>
                Call Button
            </td>
            <td>
                Email Button
            </td>
            <td>
                Book Now Call Button
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
<table style="margin-left:100px;margin-top:20px">
    <tr> 
        <td width="200px;">
            Park Name
        </td>
        <td>
            Park Viewed
        </td>
        <td>
            Book Now Button
        </td>
        <td>
            Website Button
        </td>
        <td>
            Call Button
        </td>
        <td>
            Email Button
        </td>
        <td>
            Book Now Call Button
        </td>
    </tr>


        <tr>
            <td>
                Camp Hatteras RV Resort and Campground
            </td>
            <td>
                    1
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

If you test it, shortening the park name (so that it doesn't wrap) will provide the intended behavior.  The problem is that when the table gets extended, the fixed header (which is itself a table) is no longer the same size as the data table.

Edit:  moved CSS into the code snippet so that it's not outside-sourced.

Answer (score 0):

Put your header in the thead instead of a diff table

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="name">col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data col1</td>
      <td>data col2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then style the class

```
th.name {width: 200px}
```

That should take care of the width for both the header and the data